# Nested Resource Creation in Parent Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-resources

I have a class called `Quote` which `has_many :line_items, as: :line_itemable` (`line_items` are polymorphic). A quote must have at least one line_item upon creation, so in my Quote creation form I have a section dedicated to adding line items. My routes look like this:

```
resources :quotes, shallow: true do
  resources :line_items
end
```

which means my routes look like this:

```
                     POST  /quotes/:quote_id/line_items(.:format)      line_items#create
new_quote_line_item  GET   /quotes/:quote_id/line_items/new(.:format)  line_items#new
```

In the line items section of the quote form I have a button that, when clicked, links to the `new_quote_line_item` controller action to render a line_item creation modal. My issue is that since the quote hasn't been created yet it doesn't have `:quote_id` to use in the path. How can I go about achieving this the Rails Way™? I was considering using ajax but I'm not sure if that is overkill for this situation. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You don't display it? You said it: the Quote is not created yet, so why display a link to create LineItems belonging to a non-existing record? --- You may want to have a nested form that allows the end-user to create a Quote record AND a Line Item in the same form. If this is what you want, I'll post an answer

Comment: I think that's what I'm currently trying to implement (unless I misunderstood your comment). I have a Quote creation form and within that I want the user to be able to add one or more line_items to the Quote that is about to be created.

Comment: check out `accepts_nested_attributes_for :nested_resource_name` ;)

Comment: Just watched a railscast on that actually, I think that's what I need to do! Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ajax**

You wouldn't need [`ajax`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) functionality for this - Ajax only allows you to pull data from the server *asynchronously*, which essentially means you don't have to reload the page.

--

**Nested Attributes**

What you're looking for, as alluded to by `atomAltera` sounds like [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) - which allows you to create `dependent` models from the parent

It sounds to me that you'll need to create a `quote` before you try and populate `line_items`, which is actually quite simple using `ActiveRecord`:

```
#app/models/quote.rb
Class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :line_items
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items
end

#app/controllers/quotes_controller.rb
Class QuotesController < ApplicationController
    def new
       @quote = Quote.new
       @quote.line_items.build
    end

    def create
       @quote = Quote.new(quote_params)
       @quote.save
    end

    private

    def quote_params
        params.require(:quote).permit(:quote, :attributes, :new, line_items_attributes: [:line, :items, :attributes])
    end
end
```

--

If you need any further information, please let me know!!

Answer (score 2):

You should user *[accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for)* method in your model to accept attributes for LineItem and *[fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for)* helper

Your model should looks like:

```
class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_item
    ...
end
```

And you template like:

```
form_for @quote do |f|
    f.fields_for :line_items do |f2|
       ...
    end
    ...
end
```